# Cannot paste lastest clipboard contents from other applications programmatically in Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I’m using Aquamacs, a macOS variant of Emacs. I’m writing an ELisp function that needs to paste the OS clipboard’s content. I tried using both `(yank)` and `(cua-paste nil)` (I’m not sure about the argument `cua-paste` expects, though).

The problem is that when I copy text from another application, the text pasted is not that one, but rather whatever content was last pasted in Aquamacs.

If I first paste the text manually in Aquamacs once, using ⌘V, then ulterior calls to my function do paste that, as desired.

What code can I use to paste the contents of the OS clipboard?

Comment: Have you tried `M-x clipboard-yank`?

Comment: Aquamacs tries very hard to do things the "macOS way", to the point of overriding the "Emacs way". I wouldnt be surprised if there was some Aquamacs specific functionality that was getting in your way. You may be better served by opening an issue at https://github.com/aquamacs-emacs/aquamacs-emacs. Expect to wait though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yank` command is only for [Emacs' own internal system for cutting and pasting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Kill-Ring.html), which is more powerful than your standard operating system's variant. If you want to paste contents from the latter (e.g. text you have cut or copied from another application), use the command `clipboard-yank`.